# Is there a way to get the HttpContext.User.Identity from the Session?

Tags: asp.net, session, forms-authentication

I want to run some database processing when a user's session expires, but I **need to know what user it was whose session expired.**

I was considering simply setting the `Session["CurrentUserId"]` upon login which could then be accessed when the session expires, but thought there might be a way of getting the HttpContext.User.Identity directly from the Session?

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at the [class definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.aspx) on MSDN, it doesn't looks like you can access it right from a Session's property / member.

However, They are both properties of the same object, which in your case is going to be the current HttpContext. So when the session ends for one context (understand : one http request), the current user of the context is the same as the one you are looking for.

Otherwise, you could always use a hashtable stored in cache where the key would be the `Session.SessionId` and the value would be the User identity.

Comment: Im not sure the HttpContext.Current is available in the `Session_OnEnd()` event, but will test and revert.

Comment: Confirmed, unfortunately the `HttpContext.Current` is not available in the `Session_OnEnd()` event.

Comment: Then using a hashtable  linking SessionId and User.Identity might be your solution (build this hashtable on login, and for performance issues store it in the cache).